# Linear Regression Models with Autoregressive Errors

Tags: regression, time-series, terminology, residuals, autoregressive

Model: ${y_{t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x + w_{t}, t=1,2,..,n}$

where  ${w_t=\phi_{1}w_{t-1}+\phi_{2}w_{t-2}+...+\phi_{p}w_{t-p}+\epsilon_{t}}$

Note:

- We do not know the distribution of ${\epsilon_{t}}$.
- ${E(\epsilon_{t})=0}$ and ${var(\epsilon_{t} < \infty)}$

My question is what is the residuals of my model:

Is it ${\hat{\epsilon}_{t}=y_{t}-\hat{y}_{t}}$?

or

Is it ${\hat{\epsilon}_{t}=w_{t}-(\hat{\phi}_{1}w_{t-1}+\hat{\phi}_{2}w_{t-2}+...+\hat{\phi}_{p}w_{t-p})}$?

Which one is correct?

Comment: It seems like this question only makes sense if it is not directly possible to observe w_t. In that case the second option cannot be compute since w_t is unknown. The first option seems correct.